# I want to get both stdout and stderr from subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout

I just want to do something like this:

```
>>bar, err_value = subprocess.check_output("cat foo.txt", shell=True)
>>print bar
>>Hello, world.
>>print err_value
>>0
```

But I can't seem to be able to do it.  I can either get the stdout, the error code (via .call) or maybe both but needing to use some kind of pipe.  What am I missing here?  The documentation is very sparse about this (to me) obvious functionality.  Sorry if this is a simplistic question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it that you want stdout, sterr and the return code? In that case, you could do this:

```
import subprocess
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = proc.communicate()
errcode = proc.returncode
```

Answer (score 3):

I ended up going with this.  Thanks for your help!

```
def subprocess_output_and_error_code(cmd, shell=True):
    import subprocess
    PIPE=subprocess.PIPE
    STDOUT=subprocess.STDOUT
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, shell=shell)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    err_code = proc.returncode
    return stdout, int(err_code)
```

Answer (score 1):

[subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) reutrn a value (output string), and does not return exit status. Use following form:

```
import subprocess
try:
    out = subprocess.check_output('cat foo.txt', shell=True)
    print out
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    print e
```