# My code for video aspect ratio in python is not working on vertical, but on the horizontal its working perfectly

Tags: python

```
def apply_aspect_ratio(video_path: str, aspect_ratio: str, output_path: str) -> None:

    target_width, target_height = map(int, aspect_ratio.split(':'))

    width, height = get_video_size(video_path)

    scale_width = width / target_width
    scale_height = height / target_height

    if scale_width > scale_height:
        # Horizontal padding
        pad = int(((width / target_width * target_height) - height) / 2)
        filter_string = f"pad={width}:{width//target_width*target_height}:(ow-iw)/2:{pad}"
        # filter_string = f"scale={width}:{new_height},pad={width}:{new_height}:{pad_top}:{pad_bottom}"
    else:
        # Vertical padding
        pad = int(((height / target_height * target_width) - width) / 2)
        filter_string = f"pad={height//target_height*target_width}:{height}:(ow-iw)/2:{pad}"

    cmd = [
        'ffmpeg', '-i', video_path, '-vf', filter_string, 
        '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'fast', output_path
    ]
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(f"Applied aspect ratio = {aspect_ratio} to {video_path}")
```

"i tried this approach but its still not working"

```
import subprocess

def apply_aspect_ratio(video_path: str, aspect_ratio: str, output_path: str) -> None:
    # Split the aspect ratio into width and height
    target_width, target_height = map(int, aspect_ratio.split(':'))

    # Get the size of the video
    width, height = get_video_size(video_path)

    # Calculate the scaling factors
    scale_width = width / target_width
    scale_height = height / target_height

    # Determine the padding
    if scale_width > scale_height:
        # Horizontal padding
        new_height = int(width / target_width * target_height)
        pad_top = (new_height - height) // 2
        pad_bottom = new_height - height - pad_top
        filter_string = f"scale={width}:{new_height},pad={width}:{new_height}:{pad_top}:{pad_bottom}"
    else:
        # Vertical padding
        new_width = int(height / target_height * target_width)
        pad_left = (new_width - width) // 2
        pad_right = new_width - width - pad_left
        filter_string = f"scale={new_width}:{height},pad={new_width}:{height}:{pad_left}:{pad_right}"

    # Build the FFmpeg command
    cmd = [
        'ffmpeg', '-i', video_path, '-vf', filter_string, 
        '-c:v', 'libx264', '-preset', 'fast', output_path
    ]
    subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    print(f"Applied aspect ratio = {aspect_ratio} to {video_path}")

def get_video_size(video_path: str):
    cmd = [
        'ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-select_streams', 'v:0',
        '-show_entries', 'stream=width,height', '-of', 'csv=s=x:p=0', video_path
    ]
    result = subprocess.run(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    width, height = map(int, result.stdout.strip().split('x'))
    return width, height
```

Comment: What does “not working” mean, in exact terms?

Comment: Im uploading a vertical video on this matter and i want to set on a new aspect ratio which is  (portrait = "9:16"). but it wont generate any result, it just throw me the original video again, but when a horizontal video is uploaded it is working fine and giving the result of selected aspect ratio.

Comment: It’s likely that the subprocess call is catching errors from `ffmpg`, but because the streams (stdout, stderr) are directed to `subprocess.PIPE`, and not being displayed - the errors (which might help you) are being discarded.  Try *removing* the stdout/stderr pipes from the `.run` call and let the errors display to the terminal ‘naturally’.

Comment: thank you <3 i finally figured it out. the audio on the video is the reason.

Comment: Excellent, glad to hear it!  As a tip, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18404929/6340496) as it demonstrates how to *capture* the output streams for later use (e.g. displaying errors when they occur).

Comment: Please give some kinds pof examples. What is "not working"? Maybe screenshots of original and scaled video would be helpful, or at least the original and resulting resolutions